# Create submenu in PyQt

Tags: python, menu, pyqt, show, submenu

I have a simple code for menu in PyQt, but problem is that it doesn't show a submenu. I want to show it while hovering over "More". What is wrong?

```
class Menu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self, "Menu", parent)
        sub_menu = QtGui.QMenu("Sub menu")

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-paste")
        item = QtGui.QAction(icon, "More", self)
        self.addAction(item)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-copy")
        item = QtGui.QAction(icon, "Submenu item 1", self)
        item.triggered.connect(self.function)
        sub_menu.addAction(item)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("edit-copy")
        item = QtGui.QAction(icon, "Submenu item 2", self)
        item.triggered.connect(self.function)
        sub_menu.addAction(item)

        self.addMenu(sub_menu)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme("close")
        item = QtGui.QAction(icon, "&Exit", self)
        item.triggered.connect(self.quit_f)
        self.addAction(item)

    def function(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self.parent(), "About", "Test")

    def quit_f(self):
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the parent when you create your submenu:

```
sub_menu = QtGui.QMenu("Sub menu", parent=self)
...
self.addMenu(sub_menu)
```

*Note: this is an alternative, more concise way to create submenus:*

```
sub_menu = self.addMenu("Sub menu")
```